# Sorting NSJSON arrays aren't working properly

Tags: sorting, for-loop, ios6, nsjsonserialization

In my json file I have a `title`, `subtitle`, and `url`.

I sort the `title` to set the items alphabetically, but the `url` isn't sorted with the `title` and I don't know why.

This is what i've done:

```
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfItems) {
        NSString *titles = [diction objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *station = [diction objectForKey:@"url"];

        [jsonArray addObject:titles];
        [jsonStations addObject:station];

// SORT JSON
        NSArray *sortedArray;
        sortedArray = [jsonArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *title1, NSString *title2)
                       {
                           if ([title1 compare:title2] > 0)
                               return NSOrderedDescending;
                           else
                               return NSOrderedAscending;
                       }]; 
        [jsonArray setArray:sortedArray];
```

When I press the first item in the tableView, I get get the `url` from a total diffrent `title`. 
What should I do to get the `title` to match the `url` in the tableView?

Comment: So do you expect the `jsonStations` array to be sorted automagically as well?

Comment: No.. but i kinda expected the url to follow the title, since its under the same object in the json file.. but even when i sort the url's they dont fit the titles

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS6 Sort JSON objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16418746/ios6-sort-json-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this seems like a strange way of sorting, you should use a dictionary instead of 2 arrays otherwise things get messy very quickly.

Secondly you need to pass your **sortedArray** to the table instead of the **jsonArray** currently it seems to be just trying to reset the **jsonArray**.

I would create one method to handle it like this (I have stripped some of your sorting script to simplify this)

```
-(NSArray *)sortContentWithJSONData {
    NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"title" ascending:false];
    NSMutableArray *outputArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];;
    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfItems) {
        NSString *titles = [diction objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *station = [diction objectForKey:@"url"];

        [outputArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:titles, @"title", station, @"station", nil]]

    }

    return [outputArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortedArray]];

}
```

Then you could set a global array and access it in your table view using the following...

```
NSArray *tableContent = [self sortContentWithJSONData];
```

Hope that clears things up a bit :)