# iOS6 Sort JSON objects

Tags: json, sorting, ios6, nsjsonserialization

In my json file I have a `title`, `subtitle`, and `url`.

I sort the `title` to set the items alphabetically, but the `url` isn't sorted with the `title` and I don't know why.

This is what i've done:

```
NSDictionary *allDataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    NSArray *arrayOfItems = [allDataDictionary objectForKey:@"items"];

    for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfItems) {
        NSString *titles = [diction objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *station = [diction objectForKey:@"url"];

        [jsonArray addObject:titles];
        [jsonStations addObject:station];

// SORT JSON
        NSArray *sortedArray;
        sortedArray = [jsonArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *title1, NSString *title2)
                       {
                           if ([title1 compare:title2] > 0)
                               return NSOrderedDescending;
                           else
                               return NSOrderedAscending;
                       }]; 
        [jsonArray setArray:sortedArray];
```

What happens is, if I press the first item in the tableView, I get get the `url` from a total diffrent `title`. What should I do to get the title to match the `url` and `title` in the tableView?

Any help appreciated

**EDIT:** here's the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if(indexPath.row == _currentRadio) {
        return;
    }

    if(_radio) {
        [_radio shutdown];
        [_radio release];
        _radio = nil;
    }

    [_statusLabel setText:@""];
    [_titleLabel setText:@""];

    _currentRadio = indexPath.row;
    NSString *radioUrl = [jsonStations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if([radioUrl hasPrefix:@"mms"]) {
        _radio = [[MMSRadio alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:radioUrl]];
    } else {
        _radio = [[HTTPRadio alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:radioUrl]];
    }

    if(_radio) {
        [_radio setDelegate:self];
        [_radio play];
    }



    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your implementation of `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: I have insert the tableview you wanted above.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but it seems obvious that you don't get the correct url back from `jsonStations` because you sort `jsonArray` while you do not sort `jsonStations`. In other words, the arrays no longer have the same sort order. Wouldn't it be easier to use `arrayOfItems` as the data source of your table? It isn't a good idea to have two separate arrays that you have to keep synchronized in terms of ordering. It is possible, but it isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was placed wrong, another setup for the code, fixed the sorting problem.